# How to merge two exclusive columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns and these columns are exclusive.
If the entry in row i in column1 is NaN, I want to replace the NaN with whatever in column2. How to do it quickly without iterating all the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
df.loc[df.column1.isnull(), 'column1'] = df.column2
```

or alternatively (which might be more performant),

```
df.column1 = np.where(df.column1.isnull(), df.column2, df.column1)
```

For example:

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1.2, np.nan, 3.3, np.nan], 'column2': [5.1, 6.2, 7.1, 8.4]})

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   column1  column2
0      1.2      5.1
1      NaN      6.2
2      3.3      7.1
3      NaN      8.4

In [31]: df.loc[df.column1.isnull(), 'column1'] = df.column2

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
   column1  column2
0      1.2      5.1
1      6.2      6.2
2      3.3      7.1
3      8.4      8.4
```

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work. I want to replace ith element in column 1 with the element in ith element in column2 if the element in column 1 is NaN.